# i know what is the problem with my sound in ubuntu 15.04 but i don't know how to fix it?

Tags: sound, alsa

i upgraded my hp compact to ubuntu 15.04,but i noticed that i have no sound coming out from the built in speaker of my pc.

I went to sound setting and i found that it's stuck or blocked between line out and speaker.

I see a toggle between the two speaker line out speaker line out ... when i click the speaker built in audio (see picture) i hear for a brief moment a sound ,and i can't choose between line out and speaker it's just blocked there even if i reboot or if i reinstall ubuntu 15.04 ,the same problem 
persist.

[image]

[image]

note that i have no external speaker or headphone plugged in .So what should i do ??

Comment: Open a terminal and run `alsamixer` then press `f6` and choose the right device from the list, did this help ? Also what type of connection ? ie HDMI

Comment: no the toggle is still there ,and i can't choose speaker it switches automatically between line out and speaker

Comment: Do you use a graphics card or a sound card ? If so what

Comment: i didn't add a sound or graphic card ,i use the built in cards and my sound card is  a HDA intel realtek alc 260

Comment: Where is the picture, if rep is to low upload it somewhere else (ie http://imgur.com/) and give me the link and I will edit it in

Comment: i tried adding them but the website told me i should have some points bla bla ..because i'm new to the website .Anyway here are two screenshot that shows the toggle.  http://i.imgur.com/YEcEfPQ.png  http://i.imgur.com/iuMEaf9.png

Comment: What is the out put of  `aplay -l`

Comment: *** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC260 Analog [ALC260 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: Can you do a screen shot of `alsamixer`, make sure to expand the window to get everything in

Comment: here it is http://i.imgur.com/2IqHWs4.png

Comment: You see how many of the inputs and outputs say`mm` underneth, highlight the ones you want to use (ie `speaker`) and press `m` to un mute them

Comment: hhhhhhhh shiiit ,it works ,WTH i was breaking my head for m hhhhhh thank you bro for your time and help,but the sound is a little creepy and kind of noisy crackly , i think ubunu gives  the speakers more power than they need ,i think i should install pulseaudio to fix the noise what do you think ?.

Comment: Glad to help, I will write you an answer please accept to say thanks, try to balance other options in `alsamixer` like `pcm` first but |I will include switching to pulse audio in the answer so you can try it

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was the volume levels in alsa were muted.

Open a terminal and run

```
alsamixer
```

Find the output you want to use and if it says `mm` underneath it is muted, just press `m` to unmute it.

If the audio quality is poor try adjusting other outputs levels in `alsamixer` until it sounds good.

If all else fails, switch the sound to `pulse audio`

Install this software to get a set of applications for audio management

```
sudo apt-get install paman pavucontrol
```

Search `pulse` in dash to find what was installed, setting the sound device in pavucontrol should set you to pulse audio.

Comment: guess what ,it worked fine and all that stuff but i tried to plug in an external speaker now the systems toggles like crazy between speaker line out and headphone ??? ubuntu is really wierd

Comment: Thats annoying, can you open this file `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and add this line to the end of the file `options snd-hda-intel model=mobile` and reboot